# Convert table to JSON using multiple tabs

Tags: json, jquery-ui-tabs, stringify

I am using a jQuery plugin named **"Table-to-JSON"** (http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/) in order to convert an HTML table to a JSON object. Everything works smoothly.

My problem has arisen when I use another jQuery library **"jQuery UI Tabs"** to have multiple tabs within a single HTML file.

On each tab I have a table. At the bottom of the page I have a save button. I would like to give the chance to users to press the save button and for each table in each tab the corresponding JSON object to be saved.

The problem is that when you press the save button, you can only save/export the JSON object of the current (selected) tab. Add some more tabs and then, when you try to export(alert) the JSON object of each table in each tab (only the table of the selected tab is exported) , the rest of them are empty [] as you can see in my jsfiddle example provided below.

I would like to export all the JSON objects of each table in each tab.

Is it a jQuery issue regarding IDs? or table-toJSON library does not work with jQuery-UI tabs?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide HTML or jsFiddle? without server side code, as it is not applicable in fiddle

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/ptVDm/171/](http://jsfiddle.net/ptVDm/171/) hello Chirag, I tried to do something similar to what I describe above, I hope that help you, I was trying to export(alert) every JSON object of each tab(but only the table of the current tab is exported)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's an option for the function `tableToJSON` called `ignoreHiddenRows`.

set this option to  `false` to accomplish what you need.

here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7t5cB/

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much andri for your response.